# I need a help for undrestanding REST-API for Odoo

Tags: c#, rest, api, odoo

First I will connect odoo with C# appliction using REST-API for Odoo, first I want to know how to use it with the localhost ? and second, if I can use it like the other API or not? finally, I found for example "api/Common" to login and I want to know if I should connect to that URL like API URL or not?

Rq: the link: https://odoorestapi.azurewebsites.net/Help

I'm trying to get Odoo Version Information with " /restapi/1.0/common/version " but I got 404 Not Found. Rq: I used GET method on http://localhost:8069/restapi/1.0/common/version.

[HERE A Photo of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haFqr.png)

And finally, I want to know if it is free or not

Comment: you want to use odoo rest api in localhost?

Comment: Yeah I have odoo on my PC, and I want to interface it.

Comment: What version Odoo you have?

Answer (score 0):

omar bouhajja,

**Odoo REST API Features**-

- It allows you to fetch a record from the Database.
- A record can be created in the Odoo Database.
- The user can update a record in the Odoo Database.
- It can be used to delete a record in Database.
- The user can search for records in the Odoo Database.
- Get the Schema of a Table.
- Access rights message in Endpoint response.

You can get the full detail PDF here [Click Here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/odoo-restapi/downloads/pdf/latest/)

You can find the detail description with how to **Connection**, **Calling Method**, **Manipulation**, etc.

Comment: Thanks, For example, I used  http://localhost:8069/restapi/1.0/common/version on GET method on Postman and I got 404 Not Found and I got it on other API too, I updated my question with a photo from POSTman. PLZ help

Comment: make sure to use with --db-filter=database_name.And Before calling any API, you have to log in using /web/session/authenticate using post request. The reason for the above error is odoo is not able to find session information, therefore unable to find which database to login. Sample request type: {
     "params":{
     "login":"admin",
     "password":"admin",
     "db":"odoo10"
     }
}

Comment: so I need to insert login,password,db on body of request?
ok I inserted it login:admin,password:admin,db:test_odoo
but still 404 Error

Comment: @omarbouhajja for reference how to connect and call the method refer the link - https://github.com/synconics/odoo-restapi/tree/master/docs that will help you for trace.

Comment: maybe odoo-restapi need an installation or something?

Comment: @omarbouhajja As far I know no extra installation needs only just to access you need  REST API access.

Comment: ok cool, but I'm so sorry depands github.com/synconics/odoo-restapi/tree/master/docs to get server version information just I need to applicate GET method on /restapi/1.0/common/version, but when I GET http://localhost:8069/restapi/1.0/common/version on my postman I got 404 error (Rq: depands of documentation server information no need extra parameters)